# Javascript Display Image Function: Help Simplifying Function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, button

I'm basing this off of a project that I had last semester at school. It did essentially what I want it to but it did it for an array. For what I'm doing right now, I just want one image- not an array so that I can get rid of those for loops and such.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage()
{
    myImages = new Array();
    var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");

    for (var i=0; i < myFiles.files.length; i++)
    {
        myImages[i] = myFiles.files[i].name;
    }

    var theImages = document.getElementById("images");
    theImages.innerHTML = ""; // Clearout the image area.

    for (var i=0; i < myFiles.files.length; i++)
    {
    "<img id='pic" + i + i + ";'" + " src='" + myImages[i] +
    "'" + " width = '400' " + " /> ";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage();" multiple />
</div>
<div id="images" style="position:relative; ">
Images will go here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where I'm at so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage()
{
        var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");

        document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myFiles.files.src +"'>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage();">
</div>
<div id="images">
Images will go here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far- when I click the button, I can browse for my file but all I get in the browser is a broken image icon.

Comment: myFiles.files[0].src, if you really want do it that way...

Comment: use a array literal [] instead of new Array(), it's faster and cleaner.

Comment: @Gio the first chunk essentially does exactly what I want if I only select one file. I browse, select it and the browser displays it. I'm trying to learn the easiest way to load just the one file. Hopefully with no arrays or loops.

Comment: @raptus I'd like to get away from using an array altogether. Do you think that there is a way to fix that second chunk of code? I feel like it's pretty close (this coming from a total beginner).

Comment: @user3687308 so essentially you just want code to load one image, that's pretty straight forward, however taking out the array would make your code not modular, in other words, if anybody else wanted to use your code, it couldn't be used as your code is only built for your individual situation.

Comment: @Raptus Thats exactly what im trying to do. would you mind giving me an example or pointing me to a resource? My goal is to find the simplest way to do this. Later id like to try to pass the file to php using POST. Im afraid an array will add complication that i wont be able to handle at my skill level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage()
{
    var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");

    document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myFiles.files[0].name +"'>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage();">
</div>
<div id="images">
Images will go here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm answering my own question because it was only answered with comments and I couldn't select them as answers. Thanks to Raptus and Gio for helping me get there.